# RODBC sqlSave no quoting some strings in insert query

Tags: sql, r, ms-access, rodbc

I'm trying to use the sqlSave function to insert the rows of a data.frame into a table in a Microsoft Access database. First of all, if I don't specify fast = FALSE I get a fatal error and R and RStudio crash completely with no error messages given. Changing fast to FALSE fixes this, but I get the error

```
unable to append to table ‘archiverapp_fcsfiles’ 
sqlSave conn matched archiverapp_fcsfiles TRUE TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE
```

By setting verbose = TRUE, I can see what it is trying to do:

```
Query: INSERT INTO "archiverapp_fcsfiles" ( "experiment", 
                                            "fcsfilename", 
                                            "celltype", 
                                            "donor", 
                                            "time", 
                                            "readout", 
                                            "treat1", 
                                            "treat1conc", 
                                            "treat2", 
                                            "treat2conc", 
                                            "treat3", 
                                            "treat3conc" ) 
       VALUES ( 2, 'Specimen_001_F10_F10_JUN s63_60 minutes.fcs', 'Donor 1', 
               'THP1', TNFa, '50', '60', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, JUN s63 )
sqlwrite returned 
42000 -3100 [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] 
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'JUN s63'.
[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 
'INSERT INTO "archiverapp_fcsfiles" ( "experiment", "fcsfilename", "celltype",
   "donor", "time", "readout", "treat1", "treat1conc", "treat2", "treat2conc", 
   "treat3", "treat3conc" ) 
 VALUES ( 2, 'Specimen_001_F10_F10_JUN s63_60 minutes.fcs', 'Donor 1', 
   'THP1', TNFa, '50', '60', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, JUN s63 )'
```

As you can see, it is not adding quotes around the strings 'TNFa' and 'JUN s63'.

I'm not having problems like this with any of my other queries, but then again I'm not using fast = FALSE with them so it's probably using a different method.

Any idea on how to avoid this?

Comment: I'd start by looking at the column types for the columns that are quoted correctly and those that are not. They might be different.

Comment: I figured it out partially - it's mixing up the order of the columns and the values to insert. 'TNFa' and 'JUN s63' should be inserted into the 'treat1' and 'readout' columns, which are text, but instead are going into the 'time' and 'treat3conc' columns which are numeric. I set a breakpoint right before the sqlQuery function to check the contents of the data frame I am trying to insert, and all the column names are correct. Now I need to figure out why this is happening.

Comment: It would have something todo with the way the object is mapped to the columns.